# Use `\left[` and `\right]` in separate lines with 'align'

Tags: align, delimiters

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[pdftex,svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}[defi]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[defi]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{theorem}[defi]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}


\declaretheorem[style=remark, name=Remark, sibling=defi]{rem}
\declaretheorem[style=remark, name=Remark, sibling=defi, numbered=no]{rem*}
\declaretheorem[style=remark, name=Example, sibling=defi]{bsp}
\newcommand{\defwort}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@cref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}

K&=\frac{1}{\left\Vert\Tilde{\nu}\right\Vert^6}\left[\left(\langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{11}\rangle\langle u_2,u_2\rangle-\langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{12}\rangle\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\right)\left( \langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{22}\rangle\langle u_1,u_1\rangle-\langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{11}\rangle\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\right)\nonumber\\
&-\left(\langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{12}\rangle\langle u_1,u_1\rangle-\langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{11}\rangle\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\right)\left( \langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{12}\rangle\langle u_2,u_2\rangle-\langle\Tilde{\nu},u_{22}\rangle\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\right)\right]
\end{align}

I want to use 
\begin{verbatim}
            \left[... \nonumber\\
            ... \right]
        \end{verbatim}
But this somehow doesn't seem to work
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot, use the manual scalers. `\left...\right` gives you excessive sizes here anyway.

Comment: Technically `\left<scaler> ... \right<scaler>` acts as a macro, and this its contens (fx `&` or ``\\`` cannot be seen by say `align`, that is why it does not work.

Comment: Here I'd remove all `\left...\right` pairs as they clutter your code, and only add sizes onto the four () pairs and the (I assume) [] pair. And I'd scale them manually. For example `\Tilde{\nu}` forces `\left...\right` into a size it does not need.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Appreciate it.

Comment: BTW: drop the `pdftex` option for `xcolor`, it hasn't needed it for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you already know the answer to your main question: TeX does *not* permit `\left` and `\right` directives to be split across rows. You *could* place `\left[ ... \right.` on one row and `\left. ... \right]` on the next, but there's no guarantee that the fence sizes will be the same across rows. By the time you've worked that out and determined the right non-automatic sizing adjustments (or maybe figured out how to insert a suitable typographic strut in one or both rows, you might as well perform manual sizing from the start.

I suggest you (a) switch to a `multline` environment, (b) use `\bigl` and `\bigr` for the round parentheses, and (c) `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` for the square brackets. I further recommend you define high-level macros such as `\iprod` and `\norm` instead of populating the equations with lots and lots of low-level instructions such as `\langle`, `\rangle`, and `\Vert`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert    % "norm"
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\iprod\langle\rangle % "inner product" 
\newcommand\tnu{\tilde{\nu}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
K=\frac{1}{\norm{\tnu}^6} \Bigl[
   \bigl(\iprod{\tnu,u_{11}}\iprod{u_2,u_2}-\iprod{\tnu,u_{12}}\iprod{u_1,u_2}\bigr)
   \bigl(\iprod{\tnu,u_{22}}\iprod{u_1,u_1}-\iprod{\tnu,u_{11}}\iprod{u_1,u_2}\bigr)\\
  -\bigl(\iprod{\tnu,u_{12}}\iprod{u_1,u_1}-\iprod{\tnu,u_{11}}\iprod{u_1,u_2}\bigr)
   \bigl(\iprod{\tnu,u_{12}}\iprod{u_2,u_2}-\iprod{\tnu,u_{22}}\iprod{u_1,u_2}\bigr)
 \smash[t]{\Bigr]}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate ot.